Setup Metaplex's Digital Asset RPC API for existing solana rpc node
I already have a solana rpc node running, and on top of that I want to provide methods present in this  https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/digital-asset-standard-api/tree/main, can someone suggest what all components would be needed to setup this api layer, that can connect with my existint solana node. Are all the components mentioned here required:
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/digital-asset-rpc-infrastructure/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#infrastructure-and-deployment-example

The repository does not work, I also encounter errors.
